# WiX Bootstrapper ShowFilesInUse shows app name as "A"

Tags: wix

I have a bootstrapper WiX project which can run a x86 or x64 MSI, depending on CPU.  It works well.  I set the ShowFilesInUse to "yes" so WiX can optionally kill running app or require restart.

However, if the app is running, the dialog shows the app name always as just "A" instead of the actual app name.

Just "A" nothing else.  In the Task Manager my running app clearly shows it has a name of "My App" or MyApp.exe.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\..\MyApp\WIX_Version.wxi?>
  <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\..\WiXSetup x64\Variables.wxi?>

  <Bundle Name="My App" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="My Company LLC" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" AboutUrl="http://www.mywebsite.com/tools/MyApp" IconSourceFile="..\Graphics\ApplicationLogo.ico">
    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="" />

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\MyApp\EULA.rtf" LogoFile="..\Graphics\InstallerLogo_64.png" ShowVersion="yes" ShowFilesInUse="yes" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef> 

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="x86" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.WiXSetup x86.TargetDir)MyAppSetup_x86.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="x64" InstallCondition="VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.WiXSetup x64.TargetDir)MyAppSetup_x64.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

[image]

Comment: Does your app have a main window with title "A"? You can see if there's anything that identifies itself as "A" by running something like inspect.exe (from Microsoft)

Comment: The window title is the name of my app.  I had used Active Active Window Info (Window Spy) from AutoHotkey and nothing shows up as "A" -- all the window title, text, class, etc., are as expected.  This is a WinForms .Net 4.0 app.  I'll take a look at inspect.exe to see if there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: Weird, there might be better information from the MSI logs if you run with `msiexec /i installer.mst /l*v log.txt` but I don't recall if the logs actually say anything about the program holding files in use in these logs

Comment: The "Files in Use" dialog is happening in the bootstrapper (EXE) not the MSI right?  Or maybe I'm not quite understanding the WiX workflow in that regard.  I'll check out extended logging options tonight.  Good suggestion.

Comment: the bootstrapper UI shows the files in use but the origin of the error is a message from the MSI IIRC.